# partial string matching reification in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I need to reconcile similar string to one the longest string. I am stuck with agrep, how would you do it?

**Update: better problem definition**
I have a .csv of addresses of bakeries and I want to know (1) how many branches a bakery has and (2) how many businesses there are.

I therefore extract only the names of the bakeries (see sample below) and now I need to find all the strings that are so similiar that they represent the same business. Then I count the business and the number of branches.

```
c("5 Meister Bäcker", "5 Meister Bäcker H. Breunung GmbH & Co. KG", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Amthorpassage Ba...", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Bäckerei", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Backshop", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Backshop", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Backshop", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Backshop", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Backshop", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung Backshop", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung GmbH & Co. KG", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung GmbH & Co. KG", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung GmbH & Co. KG", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung GmbH & Co. KG", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung GmbH & Co. KG", "5 Meister Bäcker Hubert Breunung", 
"5 Meister Bäcker Verwaltung", "Abel Backwaren", "Abele Bäckerei Filiale", 
"Abele Bruno Bäckerei", "Abele Eugen Bäckerei", "Abele Stefan Bäckerei", 
"Abel Lutz Feinbäckerei", "Abelmann Guido Bäckerei", "Abelmann Guido Bäckerei", 
"Abeln", " 05432 6 79", "Abeln Der City Bäcker", "Abeln", " 05933 18 12", 
"Abeln", " 05432 90 46 10", "Abeln", " 04471 72 93", "Abeln", 
" 05431 90 40 87", "Abeln", " 04471 93 03 47", "Abeln der City Bäcker", 
"Abeln Der City Bäcker", "Abeln Der City Bäcker", "Abeln", 
" 05961 95 53 30", "Abeln Der City Bäcker", "Abeln mein City-Bäcker Bäckerei", 
"Abeln", " 05933 64 76 23", "Abel Rupert Bäckerei und Konditorei", 
"Abels Bäckerei", "Abenthum Heinrich Bäckerei und Konditorei", 
"Aberle Hanno Bäckerei", "Abholzer Bäckerei Inh. Bernard u. Rosi Sproß")
```

Comment: You may also want to look at `adist`

Comment: thanks as far as I understand adist() I need to split the strings into ngram vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is not clear what do you want to do. I assume taht for each elements in you vector data , you try to find the similar longest string, or the longest string within the similars(agrep result).

1. You can first remove all the dupliacted( no sens for me to do a grep , when there is exact matching)

   ```
   stats.nd <- dat[!duplicated(dat)]   #I remove duplicated, but below
                                       # I will do the job in the origin vector
   ```
2. Assuming `dat` is your string vector , you can do smething like this :

   ```
   ll.lmatch <- sapply(seq_along(dat),function(x){
            ll <- agrep(pattern=dat[x],         # for each string
                        dat[-x],                # I search between the others strings 
                        value=T,max.distance=0.5)    # I set the Levenshtein distance
            ll[which.max(rank(ll))]                  # I choose the longest using rank
   })
   res <- cbind(dat,dat.match)
   ```

Comment: thank you I clarified the requiremens, removing duplicates is not sensitiv in my case because I want to know the number of branches a business has. the challange is that often the branches are named sligtly different

Comment: I don't understand where stats.nd comes from?

Comment: @Roo sorry it a copy paste. stats.nd I removed duplicated (nd as non duplicated) but at last I keep the origin vector(dat). I update my answer.

Comment: assuming stats.nd is dat I tried your code on 37k lines ...it does not stop after 30 mins. some ideas for performance optimization?

Comment: 30 minutes! really! what if you remove duplicated first? and comment the rank step( don't choose the longest)?